# How to reset child's style sheet to Qt default style sheet when the "child's parent's style sheet" is changed?

Tags: c++, css, visual-studio, qt, stylesheet

When I change the style sheet of an object, the style sheet of it's child also changes.
how can I reset child's style sheet to Qt default style?
for test of this I use the below code:

in header file:

```
#include "ui_QtGuiApplication.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>

class QtGuiApplication : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtGuiApplication(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);


private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplicationClass ui;
    QGraphicsView* qGraph;
    QGraphicsScene* scene;

};
```

in source file:

```
#include "QtGuiApplication.h"

QtGuiApplication::QtGuiApplication(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    // Change centralWidget stylesheet      
    ui.centralWidget->setStyleSheet(
        "background:qlineargradient(x1 : 0, y1 : 0, x2 : 0, y2 : 1,\
        stop : 0  rgb(216, 0, 0), stop : 0.4 rgb(155, 0, 0),\
        stop : 0.4 rgb(155, 0, 0), stop : 1.0 rgb(216, 0, 0));");


    // creat a QGraphicsView an add it to centralWidget
    qGraph = new QGraphicsView(ui.centralWidget);
    qGraph->setGeometry(QRect(70, 30, 300, 300));
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(qGraph);
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    qGraph->setScene(scene);
    qGraph->show();

    // creat a push button and add it in to centralWidget
    QPushButton* btn_Ok = new QPushButton(ui.centralWidget);
    btn_Ok->setGeometry(QRect(340, 340, 75, 23));
    btn_Ok->setText("Ok");
    //below code doesn't work 
    btn_Ok->setStyleSheet("");
    btn_Ok->setStyleSheet(styleSheet());

}
```

Comment: You should add a selector to your stylesheet: (https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/14099-How-to-stop-child-widgets-from-inheriting-parent-s-StyleSheet-and-use-system-default)

Comment: tank you. I did like this `ui.centralWidget->setStyleSheet("QWidget#centralWidget {"same at code"});` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and *child* or *ID selector* did the trick for me.

For instance, if you want to style `btn_Ok` which is a `QPushButton` you can give it a name

`btn_Ok->setObjectName("xxx");`

and use this name to style it via

`ui.centralWidget->setStyleSheet("QPushButton#xxx{background: red;}");`

This way the **only** push button that will be styled is `btn_Ok`.

If you want to style **all** the push buttons that are direct descendants from you central widget you can use

`ui.centralWidget->setStyleSheet("QWidget#centralWidget > QPushButton{background: red;}");`